# Twitter блокирует oEmbed?

Tags: twitter, embedded, web-scraping

На сайте установил возможность при постинге со ссылкой на Twitter скрапить твит и отображать его во фрейме.
Использую https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed/ (и это просто для понимания проблемы - проблема не в этой библиотеке совсем).

Все шло нормально в течение года-два.
Но в начале недели начал замечать, что Твиттер не отдает нормальный вид и при поиске проблемы обнаружил, что банально блокируется IP моего сервера.

Например,
Со своего сервера посылаю: `lynx https://twitter.com/QuinnyPig/status/1250910042246660096`
Возвращает 404

С localhost или любого иного IP - все нормально.

Соответственно, делаю вывод, что блокируется лично IP моего сервера.

Замечу, что таких embed постов на сайте не более 10-20 в день.

При поиске решения проблемы не нашел ничего вразумительно насчет ограничения oEmbed вставок твитов.
Да и зачем Твиттеру это делать?

Убрал все ограничения из фаерволла и fail2ban правил - проверил - проблема осталась.

При этом другие oEmbed вставки, например с FB, Instagram, работают нормально.

Да, и как я указал выше, причина исключительно в подозрительном блокировании IP моего сервера.

Что и как делать?

Если проблема в превышении каких-либо лимитов на такой oEmbed-постинг, то подскажите, где искать, потому что не нашел я такого в Твиттерном хелпе.

Я, конечно. могу воспользоваться прокси и т.п. средствами для скраппинга, но меня интересует суть проблемы - я (сервер) в этом виноват или Твиттер лимитирует такое дело.
Если последнее, то как тогда справляются другие сайты.

---

**Обновление:**

Наш team leader задал вопрос службе поддержки Twitter и в ходе обсуждений было выяснено, что (по невыясненной, пока, причине) происходит "блокировка" IP-адреса нашего сервера, т.е. на любой запрос, исходящего с нашего сервера, мы получаем ответ с 404 кодом.

При этом **авторизированные запросы** с использованием выданных нам ключей, а также работа наших приложений не блокируется!

Но такой обычный запрос, как:

```
curl https://twitter.com
```

Приходит с ответом о не найденной странице.

Comment: Напишите им письмо с вопросом.

Comment: Спасибо. Тимлидер уже сделал это и поднял тему на форуме.

Comment: Добавьте это пояснение в свой вопрос, а как получите ответ от них, напишите и сюда ответ для этого вопроса отдельным сообщением под ним.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что ж, без каких-либо изменений в коде или на сервере Твиттер, неожиданно, "вернул" нам доступ к своим ресурсам.

Полагаю, что проблема была в следующем.

В robots.txt сайта отсутствовали разрешающие правила для Twitter бота:

```
User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow:
```

Мы исправили это несколько дней назад и, скорее всего, Твиттеру понадобилось некоторое время, чтобы вернуть нам доступ (возможно, очистился кэш или что-то там у них обновилось).

В любом случае, сейчас все работает. как прежде.